# R: How to create a new column for 90th quantile based off previous rows in a data frame grouped by another column?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, quantile

This is what I have so far. I want this in either dplyr or data.table for speed purposes.

```
test <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                   b = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c") , 
                   c = c(1,7,11,4,5,5))

   a b  c 
1: 1 a  1 
2: 2 b  7 
3: 3 c 11 
4: 4 a  4 
5: 5 b  5 
6: 6 c  5 

test[, a90 := lapply(.I, function(x) quantile(a[0:x], 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)), by = b]

test
```

This is what I get:

```
   a b  c a90
1: 1 a  1 1.0
2: 2 b  7 4.7
3: 3 c 11 5.7
4: 4 a  4 1.0
5: 5 b  5 4.7
6: 6 c  5 5.7
```

I do not know how it got this.
 I want this where it is actually grouped by b and the 90th quantile of each group:

```
   a b  c a90
1: 1 a  1 1.0
2: 2 b  7 2.0
3: 3 c 11 3.0
4: 4 a  4 3.7
5: 5 b  5 4.7
6: 6 c  5 5.7
```

Comment: If you are grouping by 'b', how do you get different values for same values of 'b'.  In your code, you are getting the quantile for 'a', but in expected, it seems you want quantile for 'c'?

Comment: This looks like a task that is pretty hopeless, speedwise, unless you think up some clever algorithm for it. Anyway, one way is `test[.(b = b, a = a), on=.(b, a <= a), quantile(c, .9, na.rm=TRUE), by=.EACHI]`. By the way, in R, `a[0:x]` is not a thing -- vectors are indexed starting from 1. Also, in data.table `.I` refers to rows of the full table, so use `1:.N` if you want the within-group counter.

Comment: @Frank From the expected result, it seems the OP wants to compute _cumulative quantiles_ similar to `cumsum()`. The recently released  `cumstats` package has such a beast. Not sure what the performance is.

Answer (score 1):

From the expected result, it seems you want to compute *cumulative quantiles* similar to `cumsum()`. This can be accomplished using the `cumstats` package:

```
test[, a90 := cumstats::cumquant(a, .9), by = b][]
#   a b  c a90
#1: 1 a  1 1.0
#2: 2 b  7 2.0
#3: 3 c 11 3.0
#4: 4 a  4 3.7
#5: 5 b  5 4.7
#6: 6 c  5 5.7
```